# List files in Windows batch variable

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Please read this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I wanted to have a list of files in variable for later reuse, but unexpectedly I get duplicate files and literal "delayed variable expansion" `!variable!`.

Why, or how to have a list of files in variable, w/o complicating too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That extra `!seq!` in the beginning is what seems to be causing the duplication of the list, so chopping it off should do the trick. Use the following sequence of commands:

```
set seq=
for %f in (*.png) do @set seq=!seq! %f
set seq=%seq:~6%
echo %seq%
```

Some useful links: [String Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), [Substring Extraction](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)